# How to fit a drawing in a Google spreadsheet cell?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, google-sheets-api

I know that you can fit an Image in a cell of a Google spreadsheet with `=IMAGE()`
as we can see here https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en.

But I can´t find any way to do the same with a Drawing in spite of that Google allows you to insert a Drawing in a spreadsheet.

To clarify, what I need is to fit a Drawing in a cell.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem in the past. The only way I could get around it was to create the drawing in [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings), download it as a JPG and insert it using the `=IMAGE()` function.

Comment: Note that you don't have to download it - you can publish drawings on Google and link to them using =IMAGE(), that way changes will be preserved in the spreadsheet.